# Django-Allauth and django-facebook to retrieve Facebook profile images

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth, django-facebook, django-rest-auth

I integrated `django-rest-auth` and `django-allauth` for user registration/login using Facebook.

Now, I can authenticate (and I can create) the Facebook user and I can retrieve some basic informations like e-mail, first name, last name...

Now I need also to retrieve some profile images (last 3 user profile images) about the user at registration of it in my platform.

I'm confused because I can't use allauth to take also these informations from Facebook so, probably, I need to take it directly using Facebook GraphAPI (is correct this my solution?)

Is a good solution the integration of [django_facebook](http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 1):

The photo can be retrieved directly with the user UID and this URL:

> http://graph.facebook.com/***UID***/picture?width=40&height=40

In function:

```
 fb_uid = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=self.user.id, provider='facebook')

 if len(fb_uid):
         return "http://graph.facebook.com/{}/picture?width=40&height=40".format(fb_uid[0].uid)
```

Comment: I need to retrieve some profile images (last 3 user profile images)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entire sure, but I think you will get access to the user's photos when you add "user_photos" to scope list in facebook configuration. Did you try it?

Here is a link to django allauth documentation: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html#facebook